# Wrapping h1 around an image tag not working using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-heading

On a Wordpress website using Yootheme I m trying to wrap a h1 tag around an image that is within a class. The code does not cause any errors in the browsers console and also when checking the source code via inspector, the image tag remains as it is and is not being wrapped as wanted by an h1-heading.

This is my code:

```
<a href="https://www.skyworkertrade.ch" class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo">
<img alt="" src="/wp-content/themes/yootheme/cache/logo-swt-dbf0e8ee.png" srcset="/wp-content/themes/yootheme/cache/logo-swt-dbf0e8ee.png 270w" sizes="(min-width: 270px) 270px" data-width="270" data-height="100"></a>
```

In a snippet:

```js
$("#wrapit").click(() => {
  $(".uk-logo > img").wrap("<h1></h1>");
});
```

```css
h1 {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.google.com" class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo">
  <img alt="" src="/wp-content/themes/yootheme/cache/logo-swt-dbf0e8ee.png" srcset="/wp-content/themes/yootheme/cache/logo-swt-dbf0e8ee.png 270w" sizes="(min-width: 270px) 270px" )</img>
</a>

<hr/>
<button id="wrapit" type="button">wrap it</button>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your [code still works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114062/wrapping-h-tag-around-first-image-using-jquery) - you're just not seeing it - try giving your `h1` a style such as a border so that you can see it being changed.   I've added a snippet to your question which does exactly this - when you click the button it wraps and the h1 has a nice big border, so you can it wrapping.  What exactly are you expecting to see / to change?

Comment: Note that "view source" will reload the page without any js, use element inspector

Comment: it works, but with no effects. H1 is only useful for text values. If you're expecting some result, update the question with what is expected and what's happening.

Comment: Image tags are self-closing so you don't need the </img> tag.

Comment: @DNYX could it be browser dependent?  ie it works for us in Chrome but not for you in your browser - what browser are you using?

Comment: I m using Edge which nowadays is basically the same as Chrome. I m just confused as to why the image tag is not wrapped by the h1 heading when the code is viewed using the inspector.

Comment: What does it do in the snippet I added to the question?

Comment: I tried now to make it visible by giving all h1 tags a yellow background for testing purposed but that didnt change anything. Also display:none; in the css didnt do the job.

Comment: Well display:none would *hide* it in the browser.   Try `console.log($("h1").length)` before your code then again after - what do they give?

Comment: It works 100% as intended in the snippet you attached. I even see it as I want in the code when checked with the browser inspector. Which makes me even more confused.

Comment: console.log($("h1").length)  says 0 in the console.

Comment: If that's *after* your code, and you've confirmed the snippet works, then it looks like the code you've provided here in your question(s) does not match the code in your project / actual code.  Are you adding the a/img dynamically (ie after the page has loaded, eg via an ajax call)?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the HTML code. It should be like the example.

```js
(function($) {
  $(".uk-logo > img").wrap("<h1></h1>");
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo">
  <img alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Y23.png?s=328&g=1" srcset="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Y23.png?s=328&g=1 270w" sizes="(min-width: 270px) 270px" />
</a>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m `")</img>` The img closing tag cannot be used as such. Syntax error.

Comment: That is not causing it. Sorry i didnt paste my code correctly in. I ll edit it now.

Comment: That way it works in my browser. [image](https://imgur.com/d9nk8ld) @DNYX

Comment: Do you only see it visually taking a effect or also in the code when using the inspector? Since exactly that is my problem, I do not see the h1 tag when checking with inspector wrapped around the img tag.

Comment: I only see it on the code side. But if you write a style for H1 this will be applied. @DNYX

Comment: I did that and doesnt sadly work, the style is not being added to the img as it should when it would be wrapped with the h1 and I also do not still see it in the code when checked with inspector. I m using Yootheme and added it as a custom script if that may help.